# Orphaned rows when using ManyToManyField?

Tags: peewee

I'll take the example from the docs to explain it.

```
class Student(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()

class Course(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()
    students = ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='courses')

StudentCourse = Course.students.get_through_model()
```

At some point I want to completely remove a student from the database. This is done in two steps now:

```
student.courses.clear()
student.delete_instance()
```

This will remove the row in the `StudentCourse` through table as expected and the row in the `Course` table remains. Fair enough if other students still use this course. But what if I want to remove the course too if this student was the only one to use it anyway?

Do I need some extra logic for this to work or should peewee handle this somehow for me? I'm a bit confused at this point and since the `ManyToManyField`is so new, there's not much outside information on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide that you want to delete a Course when you clear out all the associated Students, you'll have to take care of that explicitly.